# Darkflow -- No module named 'darkflow.cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes'

Tags: python, tensorflow, darkflow

I've succesfully installed darkflow-1.0.0 (https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow) on the Windows 10 using the `pip install .` command.

```
Successfully built darkflow
Installing collected packages: darkflow
  Found existing installation: darkflow 1.0.0
    Uninstalling darkflow-1.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled darkflow-1.0.0
Successfully installed darkflow-1.0.0
```

After this, I'm trying to run `python flow --h`, which gives me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flow", line 4, in <module>
    from darkflow.cli import cliHandler
  File "C:\Users\filda\Desktop\FIT_VUT\BP\YOLO\YOLO_keras\darkflow\darkflow\cli.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .net.build import TFNet
  File "C:\Users\filda\Desktop\FIT_VUT\BP\YOLO\YOLO_keras\darkflow\darkflow\net\build.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .framework import create_framework
  File "C:\Users\filda\Desktop\FIT_VUT\BP\YOLO\YOLO_keras\darkflow\darkflow\net\framework.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import yolo
  File "C:\Users\filda\Desktop\FIT_VUT\BP\YOLO\YOLO_keras\darkflow\darkflow\net\yolo\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import predict
  File "C:\Users\filda\Desktop\FIT_VUT\BP\YOLO\YOLO_keras\darkflow\darkflow\net\yolo\predict.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ...cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes import yolo_box_constructor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'darkflow.cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes'
```

So i tried to build the Cython extensions using the `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` command, which gives me the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\filda\Desktop\FIT_VUT\BP\YOLO\YOLO_keras\darkflow-master>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'darkflow.cython_utils.nms' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\darkflow
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\darkflow\cython_utils
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -IC:\Users\filda\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\filda\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\filda\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tcdarkflow/cython_utils/nms.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\darkflow/cython_utils/nms.obj
nms.c
c1: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'darkflow/cython_utils/nms.c': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

pip show -f darkflow:

```
Name: darkflow
Version: 1.0.0
Summary: Darkflow
Home-page: https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: GPLv3
Location: c:\users\filda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
Files:
  ..\..\Scripts\flow
  darkflow-1.0.0.dist-info\INSTALLER
  darkflow-1.0.0.dist-info\METADATA
  darkflow-1.0.0.dist-info\RECORD
  darkflow-1.0.0.dist-info\WHEEL
  darkflow-1.0.0.dist-info\top_level.txt
  darkflow\__init__.py
  darkflow\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\__pycache__\cli.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\__pycache__\defaults.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\__pycache__\version.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\cli.py
  darkflow\cython_utils\__init__.py
  darkflow\cython_utils\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\cython_utils\cy_yolo2_findboxes.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
  darkflow\cython_utils\cy_yolo_findboxes.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
  darkflow\cython_utils\nms.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
  darkflow\dark\__init__.py
  darkflow\dark\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\dark\__pycache__\connected.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\dark\__pycache__\convolution.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\dark\__pycache__\darknet.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\dark\__pycache__\darkop.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\dark\__pycache__\layer.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\dark\connected.py
  darkflow\dark\convolution.py
  darkflow\dark\darknet.py
  darkflow\dark\darkop.py
  darkflow\dark\layer.py
  darkflow\defaults.py
  darkflow\net\__init__.py
  darkflow\net\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\__pycache__\build.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\__pycache__\flow.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\__pycache__\framework.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\__pycache__\help.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\build.py
  darkflow\net\flow.py
  darkflow\net\framework.py
  darkflow\net\help.py
  darkflow\net\ops\__init__.py
  darkflow\net\ops\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\ops\__pycache__\baseop.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\ops\__pycache__\convolution.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\ops\__pycache__\simple.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\ops\baseop.py
  darkflow\net\ops\convolution.py
  darkflow\net\ops\simple.py
  darkflow\net\vanilla\__init__.py
  darkflow\net\vanilla\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\vanilla\__pycache__\train.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\vanilla\train.py
  darkflow\net\yolo\__init__.py
  darkflow\net\yolo\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\yolo\__pycache__\data.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\yolo\__pycache__\misc.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\yolo\__pycache__\predict.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\yolo\__pycache__\train.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\yolo\data.py
  darkflow\net\yolo\misc.py
  darkflow\net\yolo\predict.py
  darkflow\net\yolo\train.py
  darkflow\net\yolov2\__init__.py
  darkflow\net\yolov2\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\yolov2\__pycache__\data.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\yolov2\__pycache__\predict.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\yolov2\__pycache__\train.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\net\yolov2\data.py
  darkflow\net\yolov2\predict.py
  darkflow\net\yolov2\train.py
  darkflow\utils\__init__.py
  darkflow\utils\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\utils\__pycache__\box.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\utils\__pycache__\im_transform.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\utils\__pycache__\loader.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\utils\__pycache__\pascal_voc_clean_xml.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\utils\__pycache__\process.cpython-35.pyc
  darkflow\utils\box.py
  darkflow\utils\im_transform.py
  darkflow\utils\loader.py
  darkflow\utils\pascal_voc_clean_xml.py
  darkflow\utils\process.py
  darkflow\version.py
```

I have made it working on linux, but still i would appreciate it working on windows as well. May somebode point me to right direction ?

Comment: `pip show -f darkflow`?

Comment: @hoefling Question updated.

Comment: Have you tried `python ./flow --h` from inside the clone of the repo. Their Readme file says something about it

Comment: Yeah, but since i can't install it locally with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` command, i can't use the local `flow`.

Comment: Ok, so the extension module in question is compiled and installed - what do you get when trying to import it directly? smth like `cd %HOMEPATH% & python -c "from darkflow.cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes import yolo_box_constructor"`

Comment: @hoefling I get nothing, so its imported correctly.

Comment: So it's a simple namespace clash, presumably because you're running your commands from the dir with the `darkflow` source code which overrides the installed one - running the `flow` command from any other dir should succeed. If you need to run the commands from the `darkflow` repository, you need the editable installation - uninstall `darkflow` and from the repo dir, run `pip install --editable .`

Comment: Oh yeah, its working now. Could you post it as an answer so i may accept it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a name clash: you have successfully installed the package via `pip install .`, so now `darkflow` is available in `sys.path` via `site-packages` directory. However, when you run `python script.py`, the current working directory is prepended to `sys.path`, so if the current dir contains the package `darkflow`, it is selected before the one installed in `site-packages`. Since the source code directory doesn't contain the shared object, the script fails.

Solution is either to run the script from another directory, e.g.

```
cd %HOMEPATH% & flow -h
```

or, if you need to work with the code, reinstall the package in editable mode:

```
pip uninstall -y darkflow & cd path\to\darkflow-master & pip install -e .
```

This way, the shared objects will be compiled and placed along with the source code, so you can run `flow` from anywhere now.