# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'darkflow.cython_utils'

Tags: python-3.x, cython, yolo, darkflow

I am using the **darkflow** for image processing. I have installed the darkflow  locally using `--inplace` command with the `setup.py` file. I am getting **ModuleNotFound** error for **cython_utils**.

> File "darkflow/cython_utils/cy_yolo_findboxes.pyx", line 1, in init
> darkflow.cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module
> named 'darkflow.cython_utils'

Comment: In order to be able to reproduce your issue, an [mcve] is needed. As long as it is not clear, what exactly you are doing, only guesses and no answers can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

- copy **darkflow/darkflow/cython_utils** to **darkflow/cython_utils**

and

- copy **darkflow/darkflow/utils** to **darkflow/utils**

If that does not work, try this:

```
cd ./cython_utils
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
cd ..
```

or try installing dark flow globally using

`pip install -e`

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52632847/6129428) might help.