# No module named 'darkflow.cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes'

Tags: python, yolo, darkflow

I've successfully installed darkflow on windows 10 but got the error 'No module named 'darkflow.cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes'' But the module is already there in the directory. please help me to solve this.

Comment: restart Your IDE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Darkflow -- No module named 'darkflow.cython\_utils.cy\_yolo\_findboxes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581584/darkflow-no-module-named-darkflow-cython-utils-cy-yolo-findboxes)